# Using Try::Tiny or Eval?

Tags: perl

Which is safer & better & cleaner & more recommended to use?

I used:

```
sub insert_exec {
    my ($self, $c, $args) = @_;
    my ($params, $table, $model) = $self->_init({context => $c, args => $args});
    eval {  $model->insert($table, $params);
    };
    if ($@) {  return $c->show_error($@);  } ## error
    $c->redirect("/index");
}
```

But for this kind of cases (see the error part), I have been told that using Try::Tiny is better?

My question is: How would you write this and why would you choose that way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

Thanks to an anonymous user I have been able to correct a bug in my answer. The `return` in the `catch` block wasn't having the desired effect, as it returned only from the `catch` subroutine.

If there was no exception, `try` returns the value of the `try` block, otherwise the value of the `catch` block. So this version correctly executes and returns the value of `$c->redirect("/index")` if the `insert` succeeded, otherwise it calls and returns the value of `$c->show_error($_)`.

```
sub insert_exec {
  my ($self, $c, $args) = @_;
  my ($params, $table, $model) = $self->_init({context => $c, args => $args});
  try {
    $model->insert($table, $params);
    $c->redirect("/index");
  }
  catch {
    $c->show_error($_);
  };
}
```

---

[`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny) is pretty much essential as error handling with `eval` is very hard indeed to get right in the general case. The module's documentation says this

> This module provides bare bones try/catch/finally statements that are designed to minimize common mistakes with eval blocks, and NOTHING else.
>
> The main focus of this module is to provide simple and reliable error handling for those ... who still want to write correct eval blocks without 5 lines of boilerplate each time.

Your code would look like this

```
use Try::Tiny;

sub insert_exec {
  my ($self, $c, $args) = @_;
  my ($params, $table, $model) = $self->_init({context => $c, args => $args});
  try {
    $model->insert($table, $params);
  }
  catch {
    return $c->show_error($_);
  };
  $c->redirect("/index");
}
```

which I hope you'll agree is much nicer.

Two points are notable:

- `try` and `catch` are *subroutines* coded to look like language words. That means a semicolon after the final closing brace is essential.
- For the same reason, `return` within the `try` or `catch` blocks will not work as expected, and will simply exit the block, returning to the parent subroutine. See my update above.
- Within the `catch` block `$@` has its original value from before the `try`. The value resulting from the error is in `$_`

Comment: it's much nicer indeed

Comment: An *anonymous user* who had insufficient reputation to post comments tried to edit my answer, adding this text. It is a very good point and I have made an appropriate update. *With `Try::Tiny` the construction is nicer but differs substantially from original post. As you wrote try and catch blocks are subroutines, thus the return inside catch returns only from anonymous sub, not from `insert_exec`. It means that the redirect is performed also in case of an exception. This is a common pitfall of `Try::Tiny`.*

Answer (score 4):

Not using `Try::Tiny` saves you an additional dependancy.

Using it allows you to write code which is understandable without knowledge of Perl idioms (by replacing them with terms more commonly recognised across the industry).

You need to decide which of those is of more value to you, as it is hard to measure their relative worth objectively.

Answer (score 2):

It's best not to rely on `$@` to signal errors, but to just use it as the source of error messages, so I would write it as:

```
my $success = eval { $model->insert($table, $params) };
unless ($success) {
    return $c->show_error($@);
}
```

If you are eval'ing something that might not return a true value on success, then:

```
my $success = eval { $model->insert($table, $params); 1 };
```

I would probably use Try::Tiny when things get more complicated than this, e.g., function returns a value you want to save, but might not be a true value (or might not even be defined), and you want to catch exceptions.